# How can I reconfigure a list adapter for a hashmap adapter in Android?

Tags: android, listadapter

I'm stuck getting a click listener to work properly with a ListFragment. The objective is to display a list of Likes, each of which are associated with a Category. The Category will be displayed first, followed by the Likes in that Category.  I have made a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter called LikeHashMapAdapter, which displays everything as intended. Here's the getView() method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.like_row, null);
    }

    LinearLayout likeWrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likeWrapper);

    String category = mCategories[pos];
    ArrayList<Like> arrLikes = (ArrayList<Like>) getItem(pos);

    for(Like like: arrLikes) {
        TextView txtLike = new TextView(mContext);
        txtLike.setText(like.getKeyword());
        likeWrapper.addView(txtLike);
    }

    TextView txtLike = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);
    txtLike.setText(category);

    return convertView;
}
```

In my ListFragment I'm sorting by Category:

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Like>> sortLikesByCategory(ArrayList<Like> arrayList) {

    // The hashmap value will be the category name, and the value will be the array of likes
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Like>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Like>>();

    for(Like like: arrayList) {

        // If the key does not exist in the hashmap
        if(!map.containsKey(like.getCategory().getName())) {
            ArrayList<Like> listInHash = new ArrayList<Like>();
            listInHash.add(like);
            map.put(like.getCategory().getName(), listInHash);
        } else {
            // add the like to the arraylist that corresponds to the key
            ArrayList<Like> listInHash = map.get(like.getCategory().getName());
            listInHash.add(like);

        }

    }

    return map;

}
```

And finally setting the adapter:

```
final LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Like>> finalLikeMap = sortLikesByCategory(finalLikes);

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    final LikeHashMapAdapter adapter = new LikeHashMapAdapter(getActivity(),finalLikeMap);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
```

The issue is that the entire Category section is clickable, and not just the individual Likes. Is there an easy way to fix this? Or do I need to start from scratch?

Comment: have you thought about using something like the [pinned section listview](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview)? I believe the reason why the whole "category" is clickable is because its all one view as far as the adapter is concerned, the text views you're inflating inside aren't seen as separate elements to the system.

Comment: Sort of. I checked it out and it got me google-ing a bit more and made me realize what I needed was and Expandable List View, which will be an easy swap-out. If you want to put that in an answer I'll give you credit for it since you commented first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the best was to accomplish this was to abandon my own code and use Android's Expandable List View adapter. Very convenient. I followed the example given at this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

There is too much code to post here, but it's similar to a standard Android adapter implementation. The docs are here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0):

You could make each of the likes clickable by adding a click listener to them within the loop as follows:

```
for(Like like: arrLikes) {
    TextView txtLike = new TextView(mContext);
    txtLike.setText(like.getKeyword());
    txtLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something when this like is clicked
        }
    });
    likeWrapper.addView(txtLike);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you combined the list items and the categories into the same view. The list view treats the category with a contents as a single item, that's why it doesn't work. What you should do instead is create two different item types: a category and an item within it. Then you will have no problem clicking the elements.

You could have the following lines in the adapter:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2; //One is for the elements, the other one is the category title
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //Here you tell the view which type of item it is  
    return positionToTypeMap.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Return different views here depending on the current item type
}
```

That way it's going to work as it is supposed to.